# Display images on webpage using HTML/js from server

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've to display some images on my webpage that are stored on my server. The no. of images is not fixed so I am confused that how should I construct the  tags in my client side code to display those images in HTML or javascript. I am trying this in PHP but its not working:-

```
foreach(glob($strPath."/".$FileName."/*.jpg") as $f)
{
echo "<img src='../MyPP/".$f."'/>";
}
```

It displays nothing and I can't get the image in JS for manipulation. I think this is not very difficult problem but I am newbie to web so I've not much knowledge of HTML and JS. Please suggest an easiest way to do this in HTML/JS (avoid ajax/jquery etc. if possible). I would really gratefull for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive that the glob `$strPath."/".$FileName."/*.jpg"` points to the correct location of your files? Also it seems unlikely that your `<img>` URLs are correct, as your glob refers to files inside a `$FileName` directory, while your generated URLs are in a hard-coded `MyPP` directory.

Comment: Tell us where your current page and images are located in folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
foreach(glob($strPath."/".$FileName."/") as $f){
    echo "<img src='../MyPP/".$f.".jpg'/>";
}
```